# Why can’t name the variable const, but in objects can

Tags: javascript

I wrote.

```
let const = 10;
```

and got error.and for objects everything works

```
let x = {const:10}
```

What is the difference.

Comment: There's a difference between an identifier and a property name.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Variables can be used in the same places as you can use the `const` keyword. If you could use `const` as a variable name it would be hard to distinguish between the two.

That is not the case for property names; the syntax will always be clear that it refers to a property name.

Answer (score 0):

`const` is a reserved keyword you cannot use as variable name, so the first one is invalid syntax,

```
let const = 10
```

In second example you're using `const` as key which can be any string

```js
let x = {const:10}

console.log(x)
```

Comment: Property names in object literals can be strings or identifiers, and you're using an identifier there. Reserved keywords can be used as identifiers.

Comment: @Quentin reserved keyword not as a variable name ( this is what i mean by my first line in answer), key is always strings in object literal  isn't it ?

Comment: Variable names are always identifiers. Identifiers are not always variable names. In an object literal (if we ignore computed property names) then the *syntax* is either a string literal or an identifier and the name resulting from that is a string).

Comment: @Quentin yeah true, but does my answer contradict with the point your stating here ??  pardon if i missed something in answer, let me know happy to get things right and learn more :)

Comment: You said you can't use `const` as an identifier, then you give an example (`let x = {const:10}`) where you use `const` as an identifier.

Comment: @Quentin but there's a line before example, which says in `In second example` and only that line is meant for this example, first line refer to `let const = 10`

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the statement "const is a reserved keyword you cannot use as identifier" is wrong. You can (and you are!) use reserved keywords as identifiers. You just can't use them as variable names.

Comment: @Quentin oh yeah makes sense, thanks for you valuable feedback :)